# Reverse templating to extract data from email - PHP

Tags: php, html, email

We have a CMS set up that strips information out of emails we receive regarding interested customers. We receive these emails from a variety of sources, in various formats and templates. At the moment I explode the email and search the array for keywords or use specific array indexes to extract the required information.
I was wondering if it would be possible to extract information by reverse engineering the emails to a 'template' for each source that we receive the emails from.
Example of email received:

```
--b1_ea18fa13a0b89cc5c65a05d9eff46cac
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
<br />Gigi Majola
<br />Phone: 071xxxxxxx, Email: xxxxxxx@gmail.com
<br />
<br />automatic car<br /> <br /> <br />Make: Volkswagen<br />Model: volkwagen polo 1.2 TSI Highline auto<br />End year: 2015 <br />Fuel: Petrol<br />Min Price: R120,000<br />Max Price: R150,000<br />
<br />2016-03-12 13:38:14<end>';
```

Is it possible to set up a way of extracting data in the following way?

```
'<start>' . $contentType .
'<br />' . $name .
'<br />' . $contactInfo .
'<br />
<br />' . $param1 . '<br /> <br /> <br />' . $param2 . '<br />' . $param3 .  '<br />' . $param4 . '<br />' . $param5 . '<br />' . $param6 . '<br />' . $param7 . '<br />'
'<br />' $dateReceived . '<end>'
```

Basically I want to recreate the template the source uses to send the email, then extract the variables they populated.

This is a basic example, some of the other sources have more extensive HTML templates, but unfortunately the html does not contain id's on the elements I need to extract. Is it possible to do it this way and if so, what would be the best way to go about it?

Thanks

Comment: They fill on separate inputs to send the email?

Comment: I do not have access to the fields information. A customer will fill in the form on another website we signed up to, that website will then send us an email. The first time I am able to access the information is when I receive the email.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone finds this or needs to do something similar.
I used http://www.phpclasses.org/package/8331-PHP-Find-and-view-the-difference-between-text-strings.html
I compare the email to the email body of the previously received email for that source. As the format of the source remains fairly consistent, I am able to strip out the customer information based on the differences between the two emails.